# How can I write a regular expression that matches specific first two characters and N others?

Tags: regex

The request is that the entered String in it's first two characters can't contain "*", "%" or "_"m and the minimum length is 3. What I wrote is something like this:

```
^[^\\*\\%\\_]{1}[^\\*\\%\\_]{1}
```

and now I need the end to have "put any character, at least once".

Comment: All those double backslashes are an artifact of certain languages string escaping mechanism. Please remove them or make the programming language you're working on explicit.

Comment: For clarification, language is Java and I didn't write this as a single expression because the first forbidden character also includes a whitespace (which somehow escaped during the testing/copy pasting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^[^*%_]{2}.+
```

Comment: +1 Escaping special characters in a character class is redundant. Also the expression is properly anchored. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is so short that I have to be a bit verbose, but it is

```
.+
```

Together with what you already have:

```
[^\*\%\_]{2}.+
```

Note that you must not write the backslashs twice.

Comment: Tried [.]+ and it didn't work, didn't think to try this, thanks.

Comment: +1 You don't even need any of the backslashes at all since the special characters are within a character class (`[]`).

Comment: Also you probably want to anchor the expression properly so that the *first* two characters are always matched: `^[^*%_]{2}.+$`.

Comment: Don't forget the start anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.+`. So your regexp will be

```
^[^\\*\\%\\_]{1}[^\\*\\%\\_]{1}.+
```

This will match any number of any characters after the two you have already matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regular expression like this :

```
^[^\\*\\%\\_]{2}.+
```